# Strunk & White "Others with this badge" link seems broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Using the new badge feature, when I click on "[Others with this badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk%20&%20white)" for Strunk & White I just get a blank page (go to profile, click on Strunk & White badge).

It works if I remove the "Strunk & White" slug on the end of the url.

It's broken with both:

> https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk%20&%20white

and

> https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk & white

I think it should be

> https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white

Comment: Where exactly is this link? The one on my profile page goes to http://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white?user_id=164901 Edit: Do you mean in the recent activity section?

Comment: @Jon - It's at the bottom of *that* page :)

Comment: @Nick: Ahhhh okay, I see it now. +1

Comment: Seems redundant given that clicking on the badge does the same? I think if they rejigged the order and had: "XXXX earned this badge 1 time" and then the badge with its hyperlink they could do away with that link.

Comment: @Kev It's a convenience in redundancy. Consider when [some users have exceptionally large lists](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?user_id=22656), this saves the trouble of scrolling all the way back to the top when you're at the bottom.

Comment: @grace - yeah I see what you mean

Comment: @Grace - That.....that's just ridiculous :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorted now, thanks for reporting it !

Comment: Fabby..........!